# mouseup and mousedown not working together in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Description:**

I have the following code that works fine

```
$("#pom").mousedown(function(){
alert("mouse_down");    
});
```

It alerts when the mouse is down correctly

```
$("#pom").mouseup(function(){
alert("mouse_up");      
});
```

*It works correctly when the mouse is up*

The problem starts when I put something else other than alert. In my case I am adding a class to $("#pom") on mousedown and remove the class when mouse is up but its happening in one way only. The class does gets added when the mouse is down but does'nt gets removed when the mouse is up. Any solution is appreciated :)

**Problem Demo :**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uzthcu0v/1/)

Comment: Can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code reproducing this problem?

Comment: As per the docs: `The mouseup event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, and the mouse button is released.`. If you do your mouseup while NOT over the element, then the event isn't triggered on that element.

Comment: It works properly here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzthcu0v/.  You have to inspect element and you will see that when you're hovering over the text, then click it adds the class, and then unclick and it removes the class.  If you take your mouse away while clicked it will keep the class there.

Comment: Should work just as expected, if you have an issue, post the actual code with the issue, and preferably a fiddle.

Comment: And just [one more example](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t1yjx4/) that it works.

Comment: @Regent I have updated my question with a problem demo. Please have a look and guide me in the right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto using alert to display this demo might not be a good idea, as you have to move away to click the alert message the second function will not be triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a pointer. The commented bit its causing the issue.

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(50deg);
    /*-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;*/
}
```

UPDATE:

I may be missing the point about what you want your code to do, but anyways the element wasn't rotating. Try this (tweak it to your heart content):

```
#pom
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: solid #444444 3px;
    }
    .rotate
    {
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
        -ms-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform-origin: 20% 40%;

    }
```

Finally, as Marc B points out, if you are moving the element on mousedown, chances are high that mouseup won't fire.

Comment: This is the 2D rotation ... I specially wrote in the title a 3D rotation like a door hinge..

Comment: Sorry i mixed it up with the other thing .. but still I want to rotate it in 3D and the div should come back when click is released

Comment: Check the source code of this [Flipping cards](http://css3playground.com/3d-flip-cards/)